# Evaluate $\oint_C x^2 ds$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to evaluate the line integral given by:
$$\oint_C x^2 ds$$
Where $C$ is the curve of intersection of $x^2+y^2+z^2=25$  and $x+y+z=0$.

Usually in these kind of problems one can use cylindrical coordinates to parametrize the curve. however in this case, that approach didn't help at all. So any suggestions you have would be helpful. Could I maybe use the fact that $x^2$ is a conservative field?

Comment: And using spherical and try to get only one parameter?

Comment: Your integrand is not a "conservative *vector* field" since it is not a vector-field at all; Stokes' law is no help here.

Comment: Well, if I use spherical coordinate, from  $x^2+y^2+z^2=25$ I'd obtain that the radius I need is 5. But from $x+y+z=0$ I would just obtain an equation relating the two angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant approach, but it is possible to parameterize the curve to get the desired integral: the trick to this is to find unit vectors $u,v$ that lie in the plane described.

In this case, we need two unit vectors orthogonal to $\langle 1,1,1 \rangle$. One possibility is as follows:

Let $\vec u = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}\langle1,-1,0\rangle$
Let $\vec v = \frac 1{2}\langle1,1,-2\rangle$

Not only are $u$ and $v$ orthogonal to $\langle 1,1,1 \rangle$, but also orthogonal to each other.  We may parameterize our curve as
$$
c(t) = 5\vec u\cos t + 5\vec v \sin t, \quad t \in [0,2\pi]\\
$$
and calculate
$$
\|c'(t)\| = 5
$$
from there, the integral is a matter of rote calculation.  In particular, we are left with
$$
\int_a^b c(t) \cdot \|c'(t)\|\,dt = 
\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\frac{5}{\sqrt 2}\cos t + \frac 52 \sin t \right)^2 \cdot (5)\,dt
$$

---

Alternatively, if we take
$$
u = \frac 1{\sqrt 2} \langle 0,1,-1 \rangle\\ 
v = \frac 1{2} \langle 2,-1,-1 \rangle
$$
we end up with the integral
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \left(5\sin t \right)^2 \cdot (5)\,dt
$$

Comment: How do you obtain the value of $x$ in terms of $t$?

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez $x$ is the $x$-coordinate of $c(t)$

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks!

Comment: In retrospect, a more convenient choice would have been
$$
u = \frac 1{\sqrt 2} \langle 0,1,-1 \rangle\\
v = \frac 1{2} \langle 2,-1,-1 \rangle
$$
it turns out that our integral become quite a bit nicer-looking as a result.

Comment: Just for future exercises, how did this parametrization came to mind?

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez It's simply a generalization of the usual parameterization of the circle, $\langle \cos t, \sin t \rangle$. I can't tell you whether or not this is the solution that your textbook's author or professor had in mind.

Comment: Are you sure that $u = \frac 1{\sqrt 2} \langle 0,1,-1 \rangle$  and $v = \frac 1{2} \langle 2,-1,-1 \rangle
$ satisfy the equation of the sphere?

Comment: $u$ and $v$ do not, but $5u$ and $5v$ do, because their length is $5$

Comment: But with $x=5\sin t$, $y=5/{\sqrt2}\cos t-5/2\sin t$ and  $z=-5/{\sqrt2}\cos t-5/2\sin t$. Don't you get that $x^2+y^2+z^2=25$ implies that $x^2+y^2+z^2=25((3/2)sin^2t+cos^2t)$?

Comment: You must have miscalculated. Note that $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular to each other, and think in terms of the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't...

Comment: Actually, I figured it out $u=5\sqrt {2} /2 (0,1,-1)$ and $v=5\sqrt {6} /6 (-2,1,1)$. Which gives $250 \pi /3$ as a result. Anyways, you helped me a lot, so thanks :)

Comment: Oh! My mistake. Glad you figured it out